# What are the containers in Java

Tags: java, containers

Could anyone please give me a brief full list of containers in Java? Some of the ones I know are Array, Arraylist, Hashtable, HashMap, HashSet, Node, NodeList, TreeNode, and TreeMap.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Essentially, all the docs about java "containers", or better known as collections, is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html), with the most useful page being [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html), brief [list here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/reference.html). There are other implementations of the collections framework, like the [fastutils framework](http://fastutil.dsi.unimi.it/) that gives better performance if you knew the type you were going to use. Also [Gnu Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/) is another one similar to fastutils.

Comment: 1 up for sharing links

Comment: Just for a link fix: https://fastutil.di.unimi.it/

Answer (score 3):

You can check at official [Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html).

**EDIT**

Check also the [Google Collections library](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/):

> The Google Collections is a set of new collection types, implementations and related goodness for Java 5 and higher, brought to you by Google. It is a natural extension of the Java Collections Framework you already know and love.

Edit: There was a [very nice cheatsheet for Java Collections](http://www.coderfriendly.com/2009/05/12/java-collections-cheatsheet/) which is not available anymore. There are lots of others though, like [this one](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/Java-Collections-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: +1 for Sun's Collection tutorial.  IMO, the best place to start.

Comment: @dfa - above link for cheatsheet looks outdated.It takes me to a site with ads. Can you modify the link?

Answer (score 3):

"Containers are the interface between a component and the low-level platform-specific functionality that supports the component. Before a web component, enterprise bean, or application client component can be executed, it must be assembled into a Java EE module and deployed into its container."
here is my source :
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Overview3.html

Comment: Yes, thanks for posting this. He meant collections by containers but we've all made the mistake not knowing the terms. Java enterprise beans, application contexts, etc, are abstract (but important stuff).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look-see at the [Java Collections API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html), and at [this page](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65) for more information

Answer (score 1):

A good start is looking at which classes implement [Collection<E>](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and [Map<K,V>](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I can give you a complete exhaustive list, but I believe most of the standard Java API containers should reside in the java.util package.