# Java Template and Containers

Tags: java, android, templates, containers

I'm a C++ developer over 5 years.

Now I'm starting developing for android, but I'm having trouble with Java.

The part that is like C++ is ok, but the part that is specific of Java, I don't know.

The subjects I'm having more trouble is template and containers.

Somebody knows where I could learn just the "advanced" parts of Java?

Comment: Containers are known as Collections in Java - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1288730/1029272) for some links. Also check out [the really big index of java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)

Comment: By "templates" do you mean Generics and by "containers" do you mean the [Java Collections Framework](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/collections/Collection.html)?

Comment: Java generics look similar to C++ templates at first glance, but they actually work quite differently.  I would recommend reading the Java tutorial on generics, at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about collections or containers.  If it is the latter, check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html